# How to remove a google chrome extension from blocklist

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I refer to the page

```
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/external_extensions/#preference-linux
```

there, if I understand right,  they describe how to add extensions to chrome by adding files `aaabbbcccdddeeefff.json`
of the form

```
{
  "external_update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"
}
```

to `/opt/google/chrome/extensions/`.
Here `aaabbbcccdddeeefff` must be the identifier and the extension must be in the google web store.
As you see, I use linux.

Of course, first one tries to install manually,
i.e. through the site `chrome://extensions/`, to get the ID,
but then one wants to check that the mechanism works and to that end uninstall on the UI.
Unfortunately, as the abovementioned article indicates,
this sets that extension on a blocklist, so it cannot be installed the way described.
To remove it from the blocklist,
the article suggests to add and remove on the UI.
But this seems to work no longer.

Here is my script

```
# https://github.com/simov/markdown-viewer
exts[markdown]=ckkdlimhmcjmikdlpkmbgfkaikojcbjk

exts[googleDocs]=ghbmnnjooekpmoecnnnilnnbdlolhkhi

exts[seAutoRefresh]=globgafddkdlnalejlkcpaefakkhkdoa
# Auto Refresh Plus | Page Monitor 7.5.0
exts[seAutoRefreshB]=hgeljhfekpckiiplhkigfehkdpldcggm

# VideoDowloader 2.5 videosaverpro.com
exts[vDownloaderB]=ihackilhcefdlfoehlhlamloflhofcme
exts[vDownloader]=eooikgjpbiiaebbbnjbcnmgggekfnhfj

# AVG online security www.avg.com
exts[avgSecurity]=nbmoafcmbajniiapeidgficgifbfmjfo
exts[webSecurity]=jdacdjpphmjekpfghmgfmniodedbdpih

# zoom scheduler 1.8.16 
exts[zoomScheduler]=kgjfgplpablkjnlkjmjdecgdpfankdle

for i in "${!exts[@]}"
do
  echo "install extension  : $i with id: ${exts[$i]}"
  cp ./chromeExtId.json $dir/${exts[$i]}
done
```

Any hints? Is there an explicit blocklist one could remove??

Comment: did you try to manually install the extension in chrome://extensions? you say it no longer works - in what way does it not work?

Comment: @patrick, I clarified. I think chrome shall add the extension because the json files are at proper place. I think this used to work, but no more.

Comment: I do not understand - are you still having a problem?

Comment: @patrick: sorry, i was out of office now. 
Hm yes the problem persists.
For clarification I added my script.